# android app using fragment crashes when resuming

Tags: android, native

i am developing an android app using fragment with eclipse, when i maximize(bringing the app foreground) after a long time the app it crashes. All the java class extends the class fragment.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: can you post the error log and the relevant code snippet?

Comment: You have Uncaught exception in your code. That's all that we can say about your problem, without logcat and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without stacktrace,

Let me guess,

You used some static variables and their values lost, so you got a NullPointerException. And when it occured device wasn't at debug environment for getting stacktrace :)